# Unexpected token when running `const`

Tags: javascript

I keep getting `unexpected token ';'`  error when I try to run my tests.

```
const browser; // ERROR HERE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line is invalid JavaScript.

A [`const` declaration requires a `value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Syntax).

Change that line to this:

```js
let browser;
```

...and the error should go away.